# SQL server 2005 select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables as following

table one named `tbooking` having column fields as `booking_ref_id, date_created`

table two named `tpayment_transaction` having column fields as `payment_txn_ref_id, booking_ref_id, payment_status`

I have to write a query for "Number of transaction per status per year"

the result should be like --

```
 payment_status     count       date_created
1 Progress            34         2011
2 Completed           10         2012
```

and so on....

since threre are 4 type of payment_status

Comment: You just need to add payment_status to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` from your previous question, did you even try to do it?

Comment: yes I tried ... but I am totaly new to DB concept ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming tbooking.date_created is some kind of date field. If it's a string field with the actual year like '2011', then you can exclude the `YEAR()` function:

```
SELECT payment_status, COUNT(*) AS count, YEAR(tb.date_created) AS date_created
FROM tpayment_transaction tt
JOIN tbooking tb
  ON tb.booking_ref_id = tt.booking_ref_id
GROUP BY tt.payment_status, YEAR(tb.date)
```

Comment: It should be `YEAR()` instead of `DATE()`